# Using (preg_replace) and I think my syntax is a little off. Do I need to exit something or another

Tags: php

I'm trying to use (preg_replace) to remove the directory value from $outputpid and store it in $nofolder. For some reason, $nofolder is returning NULL. Am I forgetting to exit something or is it something else?

```
$pidnum = '710';  
foreach (glob("/var/www/secure/catalog/current/programs/transfer/*.pdf") as $filename) {
    if (strpos($filename, $pidnum) !== false) {
        $outputpid = $filename;
    } 
} 
echo "$outputpid" . "<br />";
$nofolder = preg_replace('/var/www/secure/catalog/current/programs/transfer/', '', $outputpid);
echo "$nofolder" . "<br />";
```

Comment: What you really want is [`basename()`](http://php.net/basename).

Comment: And possibly `glob("…/*$pidnum*.pdf")` to avoid the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `str_replace` instead of `preg_replace` in this case, since you dont need any regex here.

The reason your regex fails, is because you "choose" slash as starting/ending delimiter of the regex, but since you have multiple slashes in your string, it will end the regex after var. This makes your regex invalid.

Either use `str_replace` instead (best solution imo) or add other delimiters around your pattern.

So your code would become:

```
$pidnum = '710';  
foreach (glob("/var/www/secure/catalog/current/programs/transfer/*.pdf") as $filename) {
    if (strpos($filename, $pidnum) !== false) {
        $outputpid = $filename;
    } 
} 
echo "$outputpid" . "<br />";
$nofolder = str_replace('/var/www/secure/catalog/current/programs/transfer/', '', $outputpid);
echo "$nofolder" . "<br />";
```

---

No relevant for your question, but you dont need to put your variables in quotes to do something with them (in this case echo'ing them out). You should go with

```
echo $outputpid . "<br />";
```

instead of

```
echo "$outputpid" . "<br />";
```

Comment: Thanks, this is going to help me make something rather crazy work quite easily within our college's CMS.